Plot annotations clipped by plt.savefig
I am plotting sunrise and sunset times using code adapted from the
matplotlib colormap examples
The code is below:
import datetime
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# Define month/year to process

d0 = datetime.datetime(2024, 9,  1)
d1 = datetime.datetime(2024, 9, 30)

xdates = [d0, d1]

# Initialise matplotlib plot

nrows = len(xdates)
figh = 0.50 + 0.15 + (nrows + (nrows - 1) * 0.1) * 0.25
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=nrows, figsize=(10.0, figh))
fig.subplots_adjust(top=1 - 0.15/figh, bottom=0.15/figh, left=0.2, right=0.99)

# Process start and end of month

for i, ax in enumerate(fig.axes):
    dt = xdates[i]
    curr_day  = dt.strftime("%d %b")
    
    # Get times
    
    if i == 0:
        twr, utr, uts, tws = (4.13, 6.30, 19.84, 22.01)
    else:
        twr, utr, uts, tws = (5.13, 7.08, 18.73, 20.69)
        
    # Create arrays for interpolation
    
    x = [0.0, twr, utr, uts, tws, 24.0, 24.1]
    y = [1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,  1.0,  1.0]

    # Interpolate for daylight
    
    xval = np.array(x)
    yval = np.array(y)
    xtim = np.arange(0.0, 24.05, 0.10)
    yngt = np.interp(xtim, xval, yval)
    
    yngt = np.vstack((yngt, yngt))
    
    # Plot data
    
    ax.imshow(yngt, aspect='auto', cmap='cividis_r')
    ax.text(-.01, .5, curr_day, va='center', ha='right', fontsize=14, transform=ax.transAxes)
    
    # Add times
    
    if i == 0:
        ypos = 1.25
    else:
        ypos = -0.75
        
    for xt in (twr, utr, uts, tws):
        if not xt is None:
            xpos = xt / 24.0 - 0.03
            tnew = dt + datetime.timedelta(hours=xt)
            tstr = tnew.strftime("%H:%M")
            ax.annotate(tstr, xy=(xpos, ypos), xycoords='axes fraction', fontsize=12)

    # Turn off *all* ticks & spines, not just the ones with colormaps
    
    ax.set_axis_off()

plt.savefig("test_sun_rise_set.png")

The plot that appears in the Spyder window looks fine:

However, the resulting PNG file has the annotations clipped

I have tried ajusting figh and the margins in fig.subplots.adjust but this just seems to make things worse so would appreciate any suggestions.  Thanks in advance.

You could try:
plt.savefig("test_sun_rise_set.png", bbox_inches="tight")

See documentation.

Thx @maxbalrog - that did the trick!

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
